# Android google maps package does not exist error

Tags: java, android, api, import, maps

I'm a french guy and I try create a software using overlay with google Maps API V2 for android phone.

I've an error message after compil and since 3 weeks I d'ont solve this problem (package does not exist) .

Does somebody can help me, please ?

REGARDS.

This is the error :
Echec de la création de l'application Android .

```
Ligne de commande : "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\javac.exe" -encoding UTF-16LE -nowarn -source 1.5 -target 1.5 -d bin\classes -bootclasspath "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-18\android.jar" gen\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\*.java src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\*.java gen\com\google\android\gms\*.java -classpath "libs;libs\google-play-services.jar"


Erreur retournée :
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:27: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
                              ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:29: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
                              ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:30: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
import com.google.android.maps.*;//GeoPoint;
^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:49: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
import com.google.android.maps.*;
^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:163: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GeoPoint
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace
private static List<GeoPoint> path;
                    ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:165: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MapView
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace
private static MapView vMap;
               ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:169: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Overlay
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace
public static class RoutePathOverlay extends Overlay {
                                             ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:174: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GeoPoint
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.RoutePathOverlay
    private final List<GeoPoint> m_arPoints;
                       ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:176: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GeoPoint
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.RoutePathOverlay
    public RoutePathOverlay(List<GeoPoint> points, int pathColor, int nOpacity, Paint.Style clStyle, int nWidth) {
                                 ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:193: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MapView
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.RoutePathOverlay
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
                                       ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:124: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MapView
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace
    vMap = (MapView) getView(sCarte);
            ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:153: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GeoPoint
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace
        path = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
                             ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:194: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Projection
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.RoutePathOverlay
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:200: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GeoPoint
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.RoutePathOverlay
                GeoPoint gPointA = m_arPoints.get(i);
                ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:209: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GeoPoint
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.RoutePathOverlay
                    GeoPoint gPointB = m_arPoints.get(i-1);
                    ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:236: non-static variable super cannot be referenced from a static context
        return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
               ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:348: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GeoPoint
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace
    path = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
                         ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:352: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GeoPoint
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lng * 1E6));
    ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:352: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GeoPoint
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lng * 1E6));
                         ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:1067: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GeoPoint
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace
        GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (((double) lat / 1E5) * 1E6),
        ^
src\com\pcsoft\android_trace_sur_carte\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace.java:1067: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GeoPoint
location: class com.pcsoft.android_trace_sur_carte.wdgen.GWDCPCOL_CarteTrace
        GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (((double) lat / 1E5) * 1E6),
                         ^
21 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

`GeoPoint`, `MapView` are few of the Classes that doesn't exists in your classpath. Add them to your claasspath.

**Update:**
Assuming you are using Eclipse, do the following in order to import Google Map APIs

1. Right click on your project
2. Select Properties
3. Select Android, check for Google APIs for Platform (your version).

Comment: Thank you for your reply but can you tell me how to put them in my Classpath because in my Java code I put this : 
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.*;
import com.google.android.GSM.maps.MapView;
 but It does not work...same error... Can you help me please ? REGARDS.